# Confirming rm in zsh

Tags: zsh, rm

After discovering 'trash-put', I would like to condition myself to use it instead of 'rm' in most cases. If I just alias it that may make me feel too safe on machines without my config files though, so I came up with the following (in my .zshrc):

```
function rm() {
    local go_ahead
    read -q "go_ahead?Are you sure you don't want to use rms? (y/n)"
    echo ""
    if [[ "$go_ahead" == "y" ]]; then
        /bin/rm $*
    fi
}
alias rms='trash-put'
```

It seems to work, but I don't have a lot of experience with zsh scripting... is this a good way to do what I want?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Probably a better question for unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: You may want to check the options `RM_STAR_SILENT` and `RM_STAR_WAIT` and perhaps use `setopt rm_star_wait` and `setopt NO_rm_star_silent`. Also this is an interesting post about scripting a safer `rm` (from people with a lot of Zsh scripting experience) http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2014/msg00114.html

Comment: I found this approach useful for making `exec' ask for confirmation :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, why make a function and an alias and not simply:

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

or otherwise transform your rm so it is:

```
function rm() {
    local go_ahead
    read -q "Are you sure you don't want to use trash-put? [y/N]"
    echo ""
    if [[ "$go_ahead" = "y" ]]; then
        /bin/rm $*
    else
        /usr/bin/env trash-put $*
    fi
}
```

so it runs `trash-put` if you do not say `y`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would rather not have to confirm every time I want to delete something. That's why I put the rms alias.

Comment: well, I usually use `rm` aliased to `rm -i`, and do `rm -f` when I want no confirmation